# MYSQL select query with two tables - never giving result

Tags: mysql

I need to get one set of rows (it will be more than 70k records) from one table which are not in another table.

Table1 : Number of records will be more than 14000k 
Table2 : Number of records will be more than 110k

So my SQL query is

```
SELECT  pre.`id` , pre.`deal_id` , pre.`coupon_code` , pre.`csv` 
FROM `customerorders` AS oc, `precoupon` AS pre 
WHERE oc.`uniqueid` != pre.`coupon_code`
```

The problem is it never able to completes.

It kept loading and at the end a white page on phpmyadmin I get this message.

memory exhausted - fatal error on PHP whatever size i have in ini_set

No results in SSH for long long time.

Is there any problem with the query or is there any optimized query for this?

**I need to export these second table records if the particular column not available in table1.**

Please help me someone. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it with left joins like this:

```
SELECT
     pre.`id` ,
     pre.`deal_id` ,
     pre.`coupon_code` ,
     pre.`csv`
FROM `precoupon` AS pre
LEFT OUTER JOIN `customerorders` AS oc
    ON oc.`uniqueid` = pre.`coupon_code`
WHERE oc.uniuqueid IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi thanks, is there any reason for WHERE oc.uniuqueid IS NULL ? Let me try it now.

Comment: Hi, it gives me a long resultset even that much not available since its join query, how i can get only not in records.

Comment: @ela i change the != to a = .... with the is null you select every record that not have joined!

Comment: This is the method I always use. It's simple and clear, and generally optimises well in the server too. I find it cleaner than using sub-queries, but that might just be habit as I imagine the SQL engines are pretty good at working these things out.
There is a reason for the  `IS NULL`, of course. What this query is saying is "show me all records from precoupon, that don't have *any* records for customerorders"

Comment: One more question, if I need common records then how the query will be?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT  id , deal_id , coupon_code, csv 
FROM precoupon
WHERE coupon_code not in (select uniqueid from customerorders)
```

using full product is not very good idea :-)